# Oracle SQL Developer: how to get back the SQL statement that had been executed?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

In SQL Developer, you can pin the query result. After running dozens of querys, it is hard to find certain one from history or SQL worksheet, but you probably know which query you are looking for by viewing the pinned query results. If you put your mouse at the tab of the pinned query result, the executed SQL to generate that result is shown as a tool tip, however, I don't know how to copy that SQL statement and exeture it again. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is re-execute the query, from the pinned query result window you can click on the `Refresh` button.

If you want to copy+paste the statement in order to modify it before re-executing, in the pinned query result window there is an `SQL` button that will show you the sql command used and will let you copy it.

(I am using SQL Developer 3.1)

Comment: My pinned Query Result tabs don't have an `SQL` button, but my colleague's does, both are version 2.1.0.63. Any idea how I get this button to show up?

Comment: Now, my SQLDeveloper has this button, but my colleague's doesn't! Any enlightenment on how to get this button to appear would be very much appreciated!